# Long lines wrap problem with zsh terminal

Tags: terminal, zsh

I have a long wrap problem with my terminal. Can anyone help me modify my prompt environment variable to overcome this issue? Here is my prompt env variable:

```
function parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/[\1]/p'
}

COLOR_DEF=$'\e[0m'
COLOR_USR=$'\e[38;5;243m'
COLOR_DIR=$'\e[38;5;197m'
COLOR_GIT=$'\e[38;5;39m'
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
export PROMPT='${COLOR_USR}%n${COLOR_DIR}@%m ${COLOR_GIT} %1d$(parse_git_branch)${COLOR_DEF}$'
```

my issue is described here https://github.com/vercel/hyper/issues/1566

Comment: You mention an issue but don't say what that issue is. Please [edit your post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/635084/edit) and add information that describes the problem.

Comment: @berndbausch I updated my post

Comment: Don't take it as nagging, but I think people are less inclined to click on a URL, and then read the lengthy discussion of your problem that it links to. Your chances to get answers will be much better when you provide a verbal description of your problem right here in your question.

Comment: Read `man zsh`. There are "zero width" characters in your prompt that must be flagged as such. None of your `COLOR_*` strings change the cursor position. In `bash` you surround zero width chars with `\[` and `\]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell zsh that those 11 characters/bytes in `$'\e[38;5;243m'` actually take no space, have zero width, so the line editor can tell when the right end of the screen is reached.

In `zsh`, like in `tcsh`, that's by enclosing them in `%{...%}`, same for all other escape sequences:

```
PROMPT=$'%{\e[38;5;243m%}'
```

You can also use `%5{weird stuff%}` to tell zsh what's inside has a display width of 5 columns. See `info zsh 'prompt expansion'` for details.

Here, though, you'd rather use `%F{243}` to tell `zsh` to use foreground colour 243 instead of hardcoding those escape sequences by yourself.

Comment: Thank u ! i modified the prompt to a simple one like the following 
COLOR_DEF='%F{0m}'
COLOR_USR='%F{243m}'
COLOR_DIR='%F{197m}'
COLOR_GIT='%F{39m}'
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
export PROMPT='${COLOR_USR}%n${COLOR_DIR}@%m ${COLOR_GIT} %1d$(parse_git_branch)${COLOR_DEF} $ '

my problem is COLOR_DEF when the background is black  it is still black it was converted to white automatically as I sometimes work on background terminals in IDe, any help

Comment: @Flupper, you'd want just `%f` to restore the default foreground colour (expands to `\e[39m`). `%F{0}` (`%F{0m}` doesn't make sense) would set the foreground colour to black (whether that's the default on your terminal or not). The `\e[m` (same as `\e[0m`) resets *all* graphic rendition settings (foreground, background colour, bold, etc) to default.

Comment: Thank u that's exactly what I wanted